# NOTEPAD++ REGEX - I can't replace what I find with nothing

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here is my regex statement which works great and highlights what I'm looking for in notepad++

```
(?<=thd)(.*)(?=]]><\/g_n>)
```

But when I try to replace it with nothing aka an empty line or a space nothing happens and it just skips to the next find.

I even tried replacing what it found with like '123' or something and that doesn't work either.

To make sure notepad++ is working properly I just did some simple regex replaces and those worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Try selecting everything in the text and check `In selection` then do the Replace All.

Comment: That fixed it. Why did I need to highlight everything and choose "in selection"? is there something unique about the regex?

Comment: I put that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure? Try selecting everything in the text and check `In selection` then do the 'Replace All'.

I suspect that your cursor was at the end of the file when you clicked 'Replace All' and the option was "Direction: Down". I do that myself sometimes without realising it only later!

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how I can replace and remove the whitespace from \s[0-9]+ thd once it's found?

Comment: @Neil I left a comment in your new question. I'm not sure I understand your question since `[0-9]+` means a number and I would have thought you used `{0-9}+`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean simply remove the space preceeding the number(s) (typo "thd"?) ?

Ctrl-H , then search for  \s([0-9]+)  , replace with \1  . make sure the mode "Regular expressions" are activated.